# ECDSA Asymmetric Encryption/Decryption C Library

Tags: c, cryptography, ecdsa

I am working with MicroChips's ATECC508a, which is a designed for highly secure hardware-based key storage. It implements asymmetric (public/private) key cryptographic signature solution
based upon Elliptic Curve Cryptography and the ECDSA signature protocol.

The device is able to create public/private key pairs, create signatures and verify them. It falls short of being able to perform encryption and decryption based on the Elliptic Curve Cryptography and the ECDSA signature protocol. Are there any "lightweight" c libraries that can do asymmetric encryption/decryption with the Elliptic Curve Cryptography and the ECDSA signature protocol?

By lightweight, this is obviously a relative term, but if it helps the code is for a ATSAMD21J18A 32bit ARM processor. So the smaller footprint the better if possible.

I am looking for options to see if this type of library is available.or do I need to try to implement one. **I am not looking for recommendations.**

Comment: Library recommendations are off-topic. I don't agree with that rule, but it's a rule.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Understood. I’m not looking for a recommendation but rather what is available

Comment: https://tweetnacl.cr.yp.to/ Maybe

Comment: Also there are commercial options https://blackberry.certicom.com/